# JSON response from a server from R - REST API

Tags: json, r, rest, restful-authentication

I am trying to pull a JSON response from a server. The problem is that the server requires a service key for me to access it and in fromJSON we cannot send a 'Header' in any way, can anyone suggest a alternate way?
Suggest a way to do it with REST API.

Here the userID is the 'Input Request Parameters' required to call the JSON response. So, can I call the JSON response with the code that I am using.

```
url <- "https://My_web service_IP_Address/services/1/experimentii?userId=1000"
key <- "04b347f4-1743-4d7e-a8e5-7ef45186e9b4"    #serviceKey For intended response
req <- GET(url, add_headers(serviceKey = key))
json <- content(req, as = "text")
fromJSON(json)
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: I recommend you place the request using a helper function from the `httr` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/index.html.

Comment: @SameerNaik I have added a sample code

Comment: @jennybryan can you explain the helper function that you specified, I am a bit new to R, couldn't catch that. Thanks

Comment: It would help if you showed the URL or at least named the service. Some services require you to use `POST` vs `GET`. You may get more of an idea what is bad by adding `verbose()` as one of the parameters to `GET`, too. You have given us very little to work with to help you.

Comment: It's hard to give a specific answer w/o specifics on what you're trying to do. Maybe look at the demos for `httr` and see if any match your situation: https://github.com/hadley/httr/tree/master/demo.

Comment: @jennybryan I have edited the question further. Is it what you were looking for?

Comment: @jennybryan I tried using the OAuth method mentioned in the git link. Even that doesn't work. It gives an error as "Unknown endpoint
" So I was unable to find out the number of end points for the Web service.

Comment: Have you tried examples shown here? [link](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/httr/docs/add_headers). Especially `GET("http://had.co.nz", c(verbose(), add_headers(Accept = "")))`. It shows how to send headers via GET request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something that can pass a key to the web service and get response. Correct me if I am wrong. But to pass the service key you can look for [RCurl package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/RCurl.pdf)

In the input parameters for getURLContent you have 'httpheader'. I think it should help you pass the key as header.
A general code would look like

```
getURLContent(URL, httpheader = c(Accept="application/json", "serviceKey" = "your_key"))
```

You might have to add other parameters according to your web service